# Make Dropdown Menu Item always have the same size as its parent? (Bootstrap & CSS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navigation bar with a dropdown menu (on hover). I would like the dropdown menu items to have the same size as the parent.

Here is a picture:

[image]

So I would now like "One" & "Two" to have the exact same size as "This is a dropdown" (at least in terms of width). Right now they are a little bit too big. When I resize the window, the parent element ("This is a dropdown") changes size, and "One" & "Two" should then resize accordingly, as it were.

**Code**

I have a navbar with different elements which is basically structured like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid nopadding navbar"> <!-- NAVBAR -->
  <div class="row">

    <div class="container-fluid col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10"> <!-- MENU -->
      <div class="row">

        <div class="dropdown col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <button class="dropbtn col-xs-12">This is a dropdown</button>
              <div class="dropdown-content col-xs-12 nopadding">
                <a href="#">One</a>
                <a href="#">Two</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
...more navbar elements follow here

    </div>
   </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Here's some of the CSS:

```
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #F6F8FB;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: AlegreyaSansSC-Light;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #637F92;
    letter-spacing: 0.52px;
    height: 81px;
}
/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #F6F8FB;

  z-index: 1;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background: rgb(221, 232, 241); /* Fallback for older browsers without RGBA-support */
  background: rgba(221, 232, 241, 0.95);
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    top: 81px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I have rather included a little bit too much here, just to be sure.

Comment: You could make the dropdown-content have a width:100% when you make it's parent position relative. Then make sure the a element is not wider than this so delete it's padding

Comment: Thank you. What exactly would the parent element be here? I would have assumed `dropbtn`, or can it only be the immediate parent? (in this case then the bootstrap class `row` ?)

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the `padding` from the `.dropdown-content a` element:

```
.dropdown-content a {
  /*padding: 30px;*/
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: but then I have, well, no padding in my dropdown menu items (everything shrinks together). It;s also still bigger (wider) than its parent.

Comment: You probably have some padding/margin from other styles in your css. Use the developers tool bar to check why you got it and remove whats necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `width: 100%;` in your `.dropbtn` and `.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content`. This should set all elements to parent width.